# Overriding invoice email template in Magento 2.3

Tags: email, invoice, overriding

I need to **override invoice email template and add a variable (po number)** in the template. I ve followed a few tutorials but they didn't help at all. I have an email template in admin panel at Marketing > email templates . I am new to Magento and don t know how to find this file and associated files in source code. Thank you

**Edit**: html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/InvoiceSender.php

i guess this is the file that i have to add an observer and push the data in transport object. I couldn't figure out how to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this first step you should do is create sample module,I'm dropping reference links for that.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-create-hello-world-module-magento-2.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

For current problem statement you have to create only required files that'll be,
registration.php, etc/module.xml

After you enable your module, Refer next steps:

Create file di.xml under etc directory with below content:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\InvoiceData"/>
</config>
```

Create file InvoiceData.php under Vendor\Module\Model directory and add below contents:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice;

class InvoiceData extends InvoiceSender
{
    /**
     * @param Invoice $invoice
     * @param false $forceSyncMode
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function send(Invoice $invoice, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {  
        $invoice->setSendEmail($this->identityContainer->isEnabled());

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());

            $transport = [
                'order' => $order,
                'invoice' => $invoice,
                'comment' => $invoice->getCustomerNoteNotify() ? $invoice->getCustomerNote() : '',
                'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
                'store' => $order->getStore(),
                'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
                'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
                'po_number' => 'Your PO Number Vaule'
            ];
            $transportObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($transport);

            /**
             * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
             */
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'email_invoice_set_template_vars_before',
                ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject->getData(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
            );

            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $invoice->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->invoiceResource->saveAttribute($invoice, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $invoice->setEmailSent(null);
            $this->invoiceResource->saveAttribute($invoice, 'email_sent');
        }

        $this->invoiceResource->saveAttribute($invoice, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
}
```

After that clear cache and in your invoice template you can use variable as below:

```
<p style="font-size: 14px;"> {{var po_number|raw}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I 've used an Observer to solve this problem. I am going to put my solution here